# How to use results of [with totals] modifier

Tags: clickhouse

We have modifier *[with totals]* that can summarize values across all rows and get the total result with key value=0 or null or smth like this
The problem is that I don't understand how I can use these values in the next calculations

Maybe I'm using the wrong format

```sql
select processing_date,count(*) 
from `telegram.message`
where processing_date>='2019-05-01'
group by processing_date with totals
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that

> You can use WITH TOTALS in subqueries, including subqueries in the
>   JOIN clause (in this case, the respective total values are combined).

Example *subqueries in the JOIN* ([CH tests scripts in github](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00150_with_totals_and_join.sql)):

```sql
SELECT k, s1, s2
FROM
(
    SELECT intDiv(number, 3) AS k, sum(number) AS s1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM system.numbers
        LIMIT 10
    )
    GROUP BY k WITH TOTALS
)
ANY LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT intDiv(number, 4) AS k, sum(number) AS s2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM system.numbers
        LIMIT 10
    )
    GROUP BY k WITH TOTALS
) USING (k)
ORDER BY k ASC

/* Result: 
┌─k─┬─s1─┬─s2─┐
│ 0 │  3 │  6 │
│ 1 │ 12 │ 22 │
│ 2 │ 21 │ 17 │
│ 3 │  9 │  0 │
└───┴────┴────┘

Totals:
┌─k─┬─s1─┬─s2─┐
│ 0 │ 45 │ 45 │
└───┴────┴────┘
*/
```

As a workaround, you can combine results of several *totals* using [client libraries](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/third-party/client_libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

Using "with rollup" instead of "with totals" decides problems with format